# facebook Live stream on my own feed using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to live stream on my own profile, do i need app review for that purpose also ?, can someone please explain as [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#publish_video) page says i need an app review??

Answer (score 0):

Certain permissions can be granted by people with a role in your app (admin, developer, tester) when the app is in live mode, even without review.
It used to be all of them, but Facebook has further restricted this since.

You will *not* be able to grant this permission to the app in live mode, even with one of those accounts with an app role, unless you get it reviewed first.

And your app *needs* to be in live mode; while in dev mode, only people with a role in the app can *see* any content created through it.

So *NO*, you will not be able to make this work and have your video be visible to everyone, without submitting your app for review.